# Extract Required Key and Values from the Object and assign it to New Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Sample Object

```
   {
    applicationId: "18848"
    bookingID: "ILID-0000056631"
    borrowerName: "ARJUN"
    collectionLastUpdate: "N/A"
    collectionNotes: "N/A"
    fundedDate: "07/04/2020"
    insurancePremium: 251.66
    interestFeesPaid: 0
    investedAmount: 156700
    isConvertedLoan: false
    isInsured: true
    loanAmount: 156700
    loanRepaymentSchedules: null
    loanStatus: "Not yet due"
    loanType: "CAUSAL"
    maturityDate: "07/09/2020"
    monthlyInterestRate: "0.67"
    principalOutstanding: 156700
    principalPaid: 0
    riskDocContent: null
    riskDocLink: null
    riskStatus: "N/A"
    sector: "Marine"
    tempInterestRatePM: 0.67
    tenure: 5
   }
```

Example, I want to create a new object with `applicationId, bookingID, borrowerName` and few others. how can i extract from above object and set them to new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const {applicationId, bookingID, borrowerName} = {
    applicationId: "18848",
    bookingID: "ILID-0000056631",
    borrowerName: "ARJUN",
    collectionLastUpdate: "N/A",
    collectionNotes: "N/A",
    fundedDate: "07/04/2020",
    insurancePremium: 251.66,
    interestFeesPaid: 0,
    investedAmount: 156700,
    isConvertedLoan: false,
    isInsured: true,
    loanAmount: 156700,
    loanRepaymentSchedules: null,
    loanStatus: "Not yet due",
    loanType: "CAUSAL",
    maturityDate: "07/09/2020",
    monthlyInterestRate: "0.67",
    principalOutstanding: 156700,
    principalPaid: 0,
    riskDocContent: null,
    riskDocLink: null,
    riskStatus: "N/A",
    sector: "Marine",
    tempInterestRatePM: 0.67,
    tenure: 5
   };
   
   const newObj = {applicationId, bookingID, borrowerName};
   
   console.log(newObj);
```

`

Comment: How can I set a new name for the key in a newly generated object?

Comment: Let's say the name of the key in the old object was "key1" and in the new object you want the key name to be "key2" and it's value to be that of "key1". So you can do: 

const newObj = {key2: key1};